# Изображение не отображается flask

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/table/<sex>/<years_old>')
def table(sex, years_old):
    years_old = int(years_old)
    if years_old >= 21:
        path = '../static/img/normal.png'
    else:
        path = '../static/img/young.png'

    if sex == 'male':
        color = f'rgb(0, {years_old}, {years_old + 65})'
    else:
        color = f'rgb(255, 0, {years_old})'

    return render_template('index.html', color=color, path=path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, host='127.0.0.1')
```

./templates/base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Миссия Колонизация Марса</h1>
        <h4>И на Марсе будут яблони цвести!</h4>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

./templates/index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Оформление каюты</h2>
    <div style="background-color:{{ color }};">
        <img src="{{ path }}">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

./static/img/normal.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDcsb.png

./static/img/young.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbNnv.jpg

По итогу работает только отображение цвета, зависящее от возраста и пола, а изображение, так же зависящее от возраста, не отображается соответствующим образом.

Comment: Раз вы используете относительные ссылки, то получается, что ссылка ведёт на `/table/static/` — и что-то мне подсказывает, что такой папки у вас наверное не существует

Comment: Во всех кодах использовал именно такой путь "../static/img/<название изображения>" и там всё работало

Comment: Работало потому что ссылки у страниц были другие. А теперь вы добавили ещё один уровень вложенности, и относительные ссылки стали вести совсем не туда

Comment: Подскажите как оставить прежней ссылку и путь файла, но чтобы изображение открывалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост надо было иcпользовать функцию url_for

```
if years_old >= 21:
    path = url_for('static', filename='img/normal.png')
else:
    path = url_for('static', filename='img/young.png')
```